# [Windows,python]How to make process started by subprocee.Popen() to automatically terminate when the parent process is dead?

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

In my python script, I started some process using:

```py
p1 = subprocess.Popen('p1.exe')
p2 = subprocess.Popen('p2.exe')
```

When those two subprocess started, they won't be killed when the parent process is dead because some error.
**I want those three process, the parent process, p1 and p2 to exit at the same time. That is any of them terminated makes all others terminated.** How could I manage this on **Windows**? What about **Linux**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the parent process is dying from an exception (rather than some hard error like a segmentation fault), a simple `try`/`finally` can guarantee a process is terminated when the block is exited (by execution running off the end, exceptions bubbling out, `return` leaving the function early, etc.):

```
p1 = p2 = None  # Ensure names exist
try:
    p1 = subprocess.Popen('p1.exe')
    p2 = subprocess.Popen('p2.exe')
    # ... stuff that runs in tandem with processes

finally:
    for p in (p1, p2):
        if p is not None:
            p.terminate()
```

If you want the child processes to close more cleanly, a simple `with` statement will suffice (the std handles will be closed, and you'll wait on each process):

```
with subprocess.Popen('p1.exe') as p1, subprocess.Popen('p2.exe') as p2:
    # ... stuff that runs in tandem with processes
```

If the processes are to be launched, and run as long as the parent process is up, you'd instead use [the `atexit` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html) to register them for termination when the main process is exiting:

```
import atexit

p1 = subprocess.Popen('p1.exe')
atexit.register(p1.terminate)
p2 = subprocess.Popen('p2.exe')
atexit.register(p2.terminate)
# ... rest of your code
```